# Composite Rest Salesforce

Tags: rest-api, callout

Can we use composite(tree or batch) rest to send multiple POST request to third party(non salesforce endpoint) in a single send call ?

Answer (score 2):

Composite API is for Consuming Data in Salesforce and not for posting data out of Salesforce to a 3rd Party System.

What you are looking for is a custom [Apex Callout](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_integration_services/apex_integration_rest_callouts), You can make callouts from SF via Button, Lightning components, batches, Triggers(via any Async) etc. It depends on your use case.